# Why my 'option' inside material-ui autocomplete is not getting inside of its textfield and returning 'null' in first hit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, react-hook-form

I am new to the reactJs and therefore the MUI. I am using MUI Autocomplete to display the countries which I brought to my react-app via (country - state - city , npm package).

The autocomplete component is displaying all the countries as expected. But, I am facing problem when I select a country from one of the **option** and register it into the input textfield.

the 'option.name' a property of country object (from country-state-city) is not getting displayed into textfield, infact, **I have to click on it exactly 2 times**, to get a value into the input field?

*into first time - my console is rendering **'null'**,
and on clicking the same option very next-time, it actually render that **option.name** into Autocomplete's textfield.*

why this is happening???

I am also using react-hook-form over the Autocomplete , since I want to send the name of the country to my API Server from this form.

here's how I got my countries into 'options'

```
const countries = require('country-state-city').getAllCountries();
// getAllCountries() - is a native method to bring all the countries into component.
```

Here's my code

Here's the [fresh sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-glitter-2w6g1k?file=/src/Country.tsx) of my problem. Help needed, as i am stuck.

```
   <Controller
       control = {control}
       defaultValue = {''} // default value of this country is empty '' string
       name = {'country'} // name is of type string
       rules = {{
        required : 'please select a country'
       }}
       render = {({ field, fieldState }) => <Autocomplete
                                            {...field}
                                            ... other properties (such as open, onOpen, onClose ...)
                                            onChange = {( event, option : any, reason : string ) => {
                                            if ( reason === 'selectOption' && option !== null && option.name !== '') {
                                               field.onChange(option.name);
                                               console.log(field.value, 'is registered');
                                               return option.name;
                                              }else if (reason === 'clear') {
                                                field.onChange(null);
                                                console.log('textfield- cleared');
                                              }}}
                                    
                                           
                                            clearOnBlur = {false}
                                         
                                            value = {field.value}
                                            options = {countries}
                                            freeSolo = {true}
                                            isOptionEqualToValue = {( option : any, value ) => option.name === value.name }
                                            getOptionLabel = {( option : any ) =>  option.name ? option.name : ''  }
                                            renderInput = {(params) => (
                                              <TextField
                                              {...params}
                                              className = {'inputField'}
                                              label = {'Employee location'}
                                              InputProps = {{
                                                 ...params.InputProps,
                                                 sx : { fontSize : '14px' } }} 
                                             
                                              error = {!!fieldState.error}
                                              helperText = {fieldState.error?.message}
                                             />
                                             )}
                                             />}
                                         />
```

the ***name*** into above controller field is meant to accept a country_name ( in string form).

why am I using option.name ?, this is because our 'countries' object (from country-state-city tool) have a 'name' property, other properties are -
currency : string
isoCode : string
lattitude : string
flag : string
longitude": string, ...and so on. (please view tool named as -> country-state-city ) on web for more info.

Comment: *I have to click on it exactly 2 times*, your *state* is one value behind. It looks like the `field.onChange` does not change the value immediately

Comment: can u print conuntries?

Comment: @HibaYoussef yes ,I could print countries ,but into options, but for the printing a country into my text field.I have to click the same option 2 times.Please check the Code Sandbox I mentioned with this question

Comment: @RubenSmn how could I solve this problem? Please refer my code Sandbox as mentioned

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're **setting** and **returning** the `option.name` instead you should **set / return** the `option`

```
<Autocomplete
  onChange={(event, option: any, reason: string) => {
    if (reason === "selectOption" && option !== null && option.name !== "") {
      field.onChange(option);
      return option;
    } else if (reason === "clear") {
      field.onChange(null);
      return null;
    }
  }}
/>
```

The reason why its logging `null` is because it updates the `field` async with `onChange`. If you look close it will always have the value of the option you clicked before. The initial value is `null` so that is why you're seeing null when you select for example `Algeria`. If you then click on for example `Albania` you'll see that the value is `Algeria`

Comment: hello @RubenSmn I got you right. But why, it is still logging null to console inside of the block for (reason === 'selectOption) ? please check console too inside of forked sandbox. Thank you